# Colored dice sample space and probability

Tags: probability

If we have three dice: red, green, blue dice. Why is the sample space $6^3$? What I think is, it should be $3! \times 6^3$. Because we can have top sides show 3R, 2G, 1B and also 3G, 2B, 1R.

And if I want to calculate the probability of getting two sixes, should I multiply it by $3!$? the reason is the same, it can be 6R, 1G, 6B or 6B, 1G, 6R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each element in the sample space can be represented by the ordered triple $(b, g, r)$, where $b$ represents the outcome on the blue die, $g$ represents the outcome on the green die, and $r$ represents the outcome on the red die.  Since $b, g, r \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, there are six possible values for each of the three entries.  Therefore, the size of the sample space is $6^3 = 216$.

In the comments, you asked why we use different colors for the dice.  If we used three white dice, there would be 
$$\binom{6}{1} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{2} + \binom{6}{3}$$
distinguishable outcomes.  The first term represents the number of outcomes in which all three dice show the same value.  The second term represents the number of outcomes in which two dice show one value and the other die shows a different value.  The factor of $\binom{6}{2}$ represents the two values shown by the three dice.  The factor $\binom{2}{1}$ represents the two ways one of those two values can appear twice.  The third term represents the number of outcomes in which the three dice show different values.

We do not use this sample space since the outcomes are not equally likely to occur.  Each of the six outcomes in which all three dice show the same value can occur in only one way.  However, each of the $30$ outcomes in which two of the dice show one value and the other die shows a different value can occur in three ways and each of the $20$ outcomes in which the dice show three different values can occur in $3! = 6$ ways.  Notice that 
$$\binom{6}{1} + 3 \cdot \binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{2} + 6 \cdot \binom{6}{3} = 216$$

As for the probability that exactly two sixes occur when the three different color dice are shown, observe that there are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose which two of the three distinguishable dice show a $6$ and $5$ ways for the third die to show a value other than $6$.  Hence, the number of favorable cases is 
$$\binom{3}{2} \cdot 5$$
so the desired probability is 
$$\frac{\binom{3}{2} \cdot 5}{6^3} = \frac{3 \cdot 5}{216} = \frac{5}{72}$$
If you instead meant at least two sixes, we gain the additional favorable outcome that three sixes occur, in which case the probability is 
$$\frac{\binom{3}{2} \cdot 5 + 1}{6^3} = \frac{3 \cdot 5 + 1}{216} = \frac{16}{216} = \frac{2}{27}$$

Comment: might not related to the initial question but I am just wondering. Is the probability of getting two sixes equal probability of getting two sixes on blue and red?

Comment: No. The probability of getting two sixes on blue and red (only) is $\frac{5}{216}$ since there is only one possible outcome on the blue and red dice and five possible outcomes on the green die.

Answer (score 1):

There are six values the red die can take on, six values the blue die can take on, and six values for the green die. So $6^3$ total possibilities. Order doesnt matter unless its stated.

If you want the probability of two of them coming up with a six, there are $\binom{3}{2} \cdot 5$ ways to get a six, and then divide that by the total number of possibilities obviously.

Comment: What I don't understand is why we use color at the first place, isn't it $6^3$ also the sample space of three dice with the same color?

Comment: @BagusTrihatmaja  If the dice are the same color, we have only $\binom{6}{1} + 2\binom{6}{2} + \binom{6}{3}$ distinguishable outcomes.  However, they are not equally likely to occur.  For instance, there is only one way to obtain 1 on all three dice, while there are three ways to obtain two 4s and a 6 and six ways to obtain a 1, a 2, and a 5.  By using dice are different colors, we ensure that each outcome is equally likely to occur.

Comment: @btcgrl In calculating the probability that two sixes are obtained, we also need to account for the outcome of the third die.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig oops, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of preference actually. If you consider the order then you multiply it by $3!$, otherwise, you don't. Technically your way is more correct.

The important thing is that if you consider that in sample space, you have to consider it in event space too. As a result the $3!$ will cancel each other out eventually at the probability stage. That's why generally we just leave it out.